# Why does python threading slow down inference time for faster R-CNN

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, python-multithreading

I am working on a traffic tracking system which analyses video that's already been collected. I am using opencv, threading, pytorch, and dectron2. To speed up frame grabbing from opencv I decided to use a Thread which runs a loop filling a Queue with frames as seen in this [blog post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/06/faster-video-file-fps-with-cv2-videocapture-and-opencv/). After implementing this I can access frames as fast as the rest of my processing pipeline can go, so no problems there. The problem occurs when I do inference (just a forward pass through Faster R-CNN model) on frames now which takes 5+ seconds compared to 0.11s in the past. My GPU is being used and my CPU is under utilised by a long shot. What could cause this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPython has a Global Interpreter Lock. This means the interpreter has a Big Lock which prevents evaluating Python bytecode from multiple threads simultanously.

Packages implemented in C and providing access to high-level operations will often be able to release the GIL when running, but if your processing code is mostly to solely Python and CPU-bound, you you won't get any speedup from multithreading: you'll have threads fighting with one another but your processing will end up being completely sequential due to the GIL.

In that case you need *multiprocessing* to get speedups, the GIL is per-interpreter so separate interpreters in separate processes don't interfere with one another. The communication / synchronisation cost is even higher though.